# Плавная прокрутка DIV

Tags: html, jquery

Есть див, при определённых обстоятельствах в него подгружается информация, соответственно размеры дива растут. Размеры дива по умолчанию подстроены под ширину страницы. При заполнении дива содержимым появляется скролл и скрипт автоматом скроллится в самый низ дива.

Для скролинга используется:

```
$('#div').scrollTo('max', 300);
```

где `300` - скорость скрола.
`max` - указатель, что див нужно перемотать максимально вниз.

Если скорость перемотки 0 - всё отлично работает, появляется содержимое и див моментально сдвигается вверх и новое содержимое мы сразу видим.
Если уйти со страницы (переключиться на другую вкладку, программу и т.д.) - то при заходе на страницу мы видим самое последнее содержимое (т.е. див при получении нового содержимого успешно скроллился вниз).

Но вот если скорость скроллинга выше, т.е. мы пытаемся визуально получить "плавную" прокрутку - скрипт начинает вредничать.
Если страница открыта, то при получении нового содержимого див скроллится как нужно. Но вот если переключиться на другую вкладку или программу (т.е. скрыть сам див из поля зрения) - скроллинг замирает, и начинает воспроизводится в момент, когда ты снова открываешь страницу. И получается эффект очень замедленной перемотки вниз, который нельзя никаким образом остановить (даже мышью) и пока див полностью не проскроллится - ничего не сделаешь. Выглядит очень ужасно:)

Почему это происходит и как обойти?
Примечательно: если переключиться на другую программу (например Скайп), и на заднем фоне программы смотреть на страницу с дивом, при появлении нового содержимого - она успешно скроллится и визуально всё симпатично, проблема возникает именно если полностью переключиться со страницы или браузера.

Comment: Можно пример на jsfiddle?

Comment: С радостью бы, но боюсь организовать такой пример будет тяжко с помощью jsfiddle:) Попробую страничку лучше сваять тестовую. Чуть позже.

Comment: Так jsfiddle - это и есть страничка. Чего не хватает-то?

Comment: Функция "прокрутки" используется в данном случае как часть соединения нескольких крупных скриптов. Т.е. по моему мнению составить пример из пары дивов, с сэттаймаутом, который будет выполнять роль "добавлятеля содержимого" - не разумно, так как, вероятно, будут упущены основные моменты "построения страницы", в которых, опять же вероятно, и кроется суть проблемы.
Проще уже показать целиком всю страницу со всеми атрибутами работы. Вероятно обнаружения погрешностей выше:)
Решил свою проблему используя **requestAnimationFrame**, так как для моих целей обычный сэттаймаут просто не подходит.

Answer (score 1):

А так пробовали?:

```
$("#my_div").animate({
    scrollTop: $("#end_div").offset().top
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Пробовал, тоже самое.

Comment: В виду того, что многие браузеры просто напросто "тормозят" работу таймаутов, если вкладка/окно не активно (особливо маленькие мобильные засранцы) - вариант с замедленным скроллом при каждом новом "сообщении" отпадает, так как это, по сути, таймаут, в течении которого скрипт двигает содержимое. Воспользовался **requestAnimationFrame** и скроллинг теперь не автоматический, при получении нового содержимого, а строго постоянный, таким образом не создаётся очередь на скроллинг, которую некоторые браузеры принудительно тормозят.

Comment: Не хочу вас расстраивать но по requestAnimationFrame сказано что:  The callback rate may be reduced to a lower rate when running in background tabs. ;-)

Comment: А чем это плохо?:)

Comment: В том что где то или когда то это может не работать.

Comment: Тут вот в чём момент: данная "функция" в современные браузеры впаривается по умолчанию, и при попытке использовать setInterval с очень маленьким промежутком - "умный браузер" останавливает выполнение такой функции (по понятным причинам производительности) и выдаёт ошибку в консоль о том, что данный браузер умеет работать с rAF. Если мы используем как раз таки rAF - то здесь два варианта: либо браузер воспринимает функцию как надо, либо, если есть какие-либо проблемы или rAF не поддерживается - использует обычный setInterval. Таким образом в минусе мы не остаёмся, а если работает - то даже в +)

Comment: Сказано же однозначно что: depending on the browser, this may cause the animation to run less smoothly than desired. Поэтому что вы пытаетесь доказать мне не понятно.

Comment: Всё верно. Организовать успешную работу "анимации" при больших нагрузках (не просто крутящееся колёсико) на JS не так уж и просто. rAF упрощает некоторые задачи, но в некоторых случаях он не идеален конечно же, но в таких случаях работа программы будет не хуже, ежели бы она была написана с помощью обычных таймаутов.
Это я и говорю: какие бы не были загвоздки - работа не будет выполнена хуже, чем нежели работа была вообще без rAF, именно об этом и говорят те строки, которые вы мне цитируете.
Всё что пришло в голову я уже перепротестил:)